# Carousel tailwind on slide event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I would like to do some changes to the Ui by sliding the slider with Carousel tailwind and NextJS, yet I have no idea to do so?!

this is an example of my code

```
...
  const slider = sliderData.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <>
        <div
          className={`carousel-item ${
            index == 0 && "active"
          } relative float-left w-full`}
        >
          <Link href={item.link + `?storeId=${state.id}`}>
            <button className="block w-full">
              <img src={item.image} className="block w-full" alt="..." />
            </button>
          </Link>
          <div className="carousel-caption hidden md:block absolute text-center">
            <h5 className="text-xl">{item.title}</h5>
            <p>{item.description}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  });


  const sliderButton = sliderData.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <>
        <button
          type="button"
          data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions"
          data-bs-slide-to={`${index}`}
          className="active"
          aria-current="true"
          aria-label={item.title}
        ></button>
      </>
    );
  });

...
  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex flex-col">
        <div
          id="carouselExampleCaptions"
          className="carousel slide relative w-screen"
          data-bs-ride="carousel"
        >
          <div className="carousel-indicators absolute right-0 bottom-0 left-0 flex justify-center p-0 mb-4">
            {sliderButton}
          </div>
          <div className="carousel-inner relative w-full overflow-hidden">
            {slider}
          </div>
          <button
            className="carousel-control-prev absolute top-0 bottom-0 flex items-center justify-center p-0 text-center border-0 hover:outline-none hover:no-underline focus:outline-none focus:no-underline left-0"
            type="button"
            data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions"
            data-bs-slide="prev"
          >
            <span
              className="carousel-control-prev-icon inline-block bg-no-repeat"
              aria-hidden="true"
            ></span>
            <span className="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
          </button>
          <button
            className="carousel-control-next absolute top-0 bottom-0 flex items-center justify-center p-0 text-center border-0 hover:outline-none hover:no-underline focus:outline-none focus:no-underline right-0"
            type="button"
            data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions"
            data-bs-slide="next"
          >
            <span
              className="carousel-control-next-icon inline-block bg-no-repeat"
              aria-hidden="true"
            ></span>
            <span className="visually-hidden">Next</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>
         
            <CatalogView
              store={state.loadedStore}
              categories={state.loadedCategories}
              products={state.loadedProducts}
              selectedCategory={state.selectedCategory}
            />
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

the changes I'm trying to do is to change the selectedCategory on slide, which are stored in the state object and the state hook to change them, yet how to let's say if the user tap on next or slide the slider to call setState.